# How to avoid getting repeated list in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, scroll

I have created the list view builder with future builder, Where I am getting the next page details when I reached to the end of the page but the list is getting repeated. For example, when I reach the end of the first page again, I am getting the first page list and again when I reach the end of the page then it displays the second page list. Can anyone help me to avoid getting repeated list.

```
class Herbs extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  Herbs(this.title);

  @override
  _HerbsState createState() => new _HerbsState();
}

class _HerbsState extends State<Herbs> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  var cname;
  String gcm;
  List pages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pages = [];
    if (gcm == null) {
      gcm = '';
      this.fetchPost(gcm);
    } else {
      this.fetchPost(gcm);
    }
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        setState(() {
          print('Page reached end of page');
          fetchPost(gcm);
        });
      }
    });
  }


  Future<Herbslist> fetchPost(gcm) async {
    String url =
        'https://example.org/api.php?action=query&gcmtitle=Category:$cname&pilimit=max&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=200&generator=categorymembers&format=json&gcmcontinue=$gcm';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = Herbslist.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      return data;
    } else {
      throw (e) {
        print("Exception thrown: $e");
        Exception(e);
      };
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    cname = widget.title;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Align(
          alignment: Alignment(-0.2, 0.3),
          child: Text(
            cname,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Herbslist>(
          future: fetchPost(gcm),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              // List pages = snapshot.data.query.pages.values.toList();
              pages.addAll(snapshot.data.query.pages.values);
              return Scrollbar(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: pages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    gcm = snapshot.data.herbslistContinue.gcmcontinue;
                    var img = pages[index].thumbnail.source;
                    return Container(
                        child: Card(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Detailpage(
                                        pages[index].title,
                                      ),
                                    ));
                              },
                              child: ListTile(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 8.0),
                                leading: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                      border: new Border(
                                          right: new BorderSide(
                                              width: 1.5, color: Colors.grey)),
                                    ),
                                    // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
                                    child: img == img.isEmpty
                                        ? SizedBox(
                                      height: 50.0,
                                      width: 50.0,
                                      child: Image.asset('image.png'),
                                    )
                                        : SizedBox(
                                      height: 50.0,
                                      width: 50.0,
                                      child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                        placeholder: 'image.png',
                                        image: img,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      ),
                                    )),
                                title: Text(pages[index].title),
                              ),
                            )));
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "gcmcontinue": "page|41434143494120464552525547494e4541202d204152494d45444148|3704",
        "continue": "gcmcontinue||"
    },
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "225": {
                "pageid": 225,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Abrus precatorius - Gunja",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "source": "https://example.org/images/thumb/c/cb/Abrus_precatorius_%281463017430%29.jpg/600px-Abrus_precatorius_%281463017430%29.jpg",
                    "width": 600,
                    "height": 450
                },
                "pageimage": "Abrus_precatorius_(1463017430).jpg"
            },
            "625": {
                "pageid": 625,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Abies webbiana - Talispatra",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "source": "https://example.org/images/thumb/b/b1/Red_fir.jpg/397px-Red_fir.jpg",
                    "width": 397,
                    "height": 600
                },
                "pageimage": "Red_fir.jpg"
            },
            "15995": {
                "pageid": 15995,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Abelmoschus esculentus - Bhenda",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/India_-_Koyambedu_Market_-_Ladies_Finger_03_%283986242135%29.jpg/600px-India_-_Koyambedu_Market_-_Ladies_Finger_03_%283986242135%29.jpg",
                    "width": 600,
                    "height": 450
                },
                "pageimage": "India_-_Koyambedu_Market_-_Ladies_Finger_03_(3986242135).jpg"
            }
        }
    },
    "limits": {
        "pageimages": 500
    }
}
```

class.dart

```
class Herbslist {
    String batchcomplete;
    Continue herbslistContinue;
    Query query;
    Limits limits;

    Herbslist({
        this.batchcomplete,
        this.herbslistContinue,
        this.query,
        this.limits,
    });

    factory Herbslist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Herbslist(
        batchcomplete: json["batchcomplete"] == null ? null : json["batchcomplete"],
        herbslistContinue: json["continue"] == null ? Continue(gcmcontinue:'0',continueContinue: '') : Continue.fromJson(json["continue"]),
        query: json["query"] == null ? null : Query.fromJson(json["query"]),
        limits: json["limits"] == null ? null : Limits.fromJson(json["limits"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "batchcomplete": batchcomplete == null ? null : batchcomplete,
        "continue": herbslistContinue == null ? null : herbslistContinue.toJson(),
        "query": query == null ? null : query.toJson(),
        "limits": limits == null ? null : limits.toJson(),
    };
}

class Continue {
    String gcmcontinue;
    String continueContinue;

    Continue({
        this.gcmcontinue,
        this.continueContinue,
    });

    factory Continue.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Continue(
        gcmcontinue: json["gcmcontinue"] == null ? null : json["gcmcontinue"],
        continueContinue: json["continue"] == null ? null : json["continue"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "gcmcontinue": gcmcontinue == null ? null : gcmcontinue,
        "continue": continueContinue == null ? null : continueContinue,
    };
}

class Limits {
    int pageimages;

    Limits({
        this.pageimages,
    });

    factory Limits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Limits(
        pageimages: json["pageimages"] == null ? null : json["pageimages"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "pageimages": pageimages == null ? null : pageimages,
    };
}

class Query {
    Map<String, Page> pages;

    Query({
        this.pages,
    });

    factory Query.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Query(
        pages: json["pages"] == null ? null : Map.from(json["pages"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Page>(k, Page.fromJson(v))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "pages": pages == null ? null : Map.from(pages).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
    };
}

class Page {
    int pageid;
    int ns;
    String title;
    Thumbnail thumbnail;
    String pageimage;

    Page({
        this.pageid,
        this.ns,
        this.title,
        this.thumbnail,
        this.pageimage,
    });

    factory Page.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Page(
        pageid: json["pageid"] == null ? null : json["pageid"],
        ns: json["ns"] == null ? null : json["ns"],
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
        thumbnail: json["thumbnail"] == null ? Thumbnail(source:'',width:0,height:0) : Thumbnail.fromJson(json["thumbnail"]),
        pageimage: json["pageimage"] == null ? null : json["pageimage"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "pageid": pageid == null ? null : pageid,
        "ns": ns == null ? null : ns,
        "title": title == null ? null : title,
        "thumbnail": thumbnail == null ? null : thumbnail.toJson(),
        "pageimage": pageimage == null ? null : pageimage,
    };
}

class Thumbnail {
    String source;
    int width;
    int height;

    Thumbnail({
        this.source,
        this.width,
        this.height,
    });

    factory Thumbnail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Thumbnail(
        source: json["source"] == null ? null : json["source"],
        width: json["width"] == null ? null : json["width"],
        height: json["height"] == null ? null : json["height"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "source": source == null ? null : source,
        "width": width == null ? null : width,
        "height": height == null ? null : height,
    };
}
```

Comment: use key for preventing repetations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I think this is happening because of this line:

```
pages.addAll(snapshot.data.query.pages.values);
```

bug happens because every time **FutureBuilder** runs, the data appends to **pages** array, contains repetetive content.
You should do this every time:

```
pages = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

the first issue i see is in your initState method. in initState super.InitState should be the first line. This may not be causing the issue you're experiencing though.

secondly your listener on the scroll controller is calling setState, and running the network request, which also rebuilds the entire FutureBuilder - which also runs your network request again since you passed the function directly into the 'future' parameter.

Try breaking your widget into smaller chunks and it may become clearer where the problem is.